Expand a 2d curve into a 3d path curve with a fixed axis of rotation?
Given a string of fonts, such as "ABC", give a space line, how to rotate around the line while expanding the string into several curves.


Each point on the letter rotates around an axis by a certain angle to form a new 3D curve.
Clear["`*"]; vt1 = {-3, -4, 0}; vt2 = {-3, 4, 0};
reg = BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[
   BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics[
    Text[Style["\[Pi]", Bold, FontFamily -> "Times"]], _Text, 
    MaxCellMeasure -> {"Length" -> 0.1/2}]];
pts1 = MeshCoordinates[reg];
pts2 = pts1 /. {x_, y_} :> {x, y, 0};
pts3 = Append[pts2, pts2[[1]]];
len = Length@pts3;
pts4 = Table[
   RotationTransform[i*2 Pi/(len - 1), vt1 - vt2, (vt1 + vt2)/2]@
    pts3[[i]], {i, 1, len - 1, 1}];
pts5 = Append[pts4, pts3[[len]]];
rg = 8;
Graphics3D[{Line[{vt1, vt2}], Line@pts3, Point[pts3[[1]]]}, 
 Axes -> True, PlotRange -> 12, AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}, 
 ViewPoint -> {0, 0, 12}]
Manipulate[
 Show[Graphics3D[{Thickness[.01/2], Red, Line@Take[pts3, len - n + 1],
     Darker@Green, 
    Line[RotationTransform[(n - 1)/len*2 Pi, 
       vt1 - vt2, (vt1 + vt2)/2]@pts5]}, Axes -> False, 
   PlotRange -> rg, ViewAngle -> 0.174502, 
   ViewPoint -> {6.20078, 3.50102, 4.15851}, 
   ViewVertical -> {0.636422, 0.631119, 0.443459}, Boxed -> False, 
   Background -> Black, Lighting -> {{"Ambient", White}}], 
  ContourPlot3D[z == 0, {x, -rg, rg}, {y, -rg, rg}, {z, -rg, rg}, 
   Mesh -> None, ContourStyle -> Opacity[0.8]]], {{n, 1, "n"}, len, 
  1, -1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, SaveDefinitions -> True, 
 ControlPlacement -> Top]


This code lacks generality and is not applicable to letters that cannot be drawn in one stroke. If the MMA version > 12.2, it would be better to use the sampling method from @CVGMT for the reg variable.
Update 1:
Support for letters with holes.
Clear["`*"]; vt1 = {-3, -4, 0}; vt2 = {-3, 4, 0};
polys = #["BoundaryPolygons"] &@
   BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics[
    Text[Style["õ", FontFamily -> "Cambria"]], _Text, 
    MaxCellMeasure -> {"Length" -> 0.2}];
\[Delta] = 1/4;
lines = MeshPrimitives[#, 1] & /@ polys;
pts1 = Map[
   Subdivide[Sequence @@ First@#, Ceiling[ArcLength@#/\[Delta]]] &, 
   lines, {2}];
pts2 = Map[Apply[Join], pts1];
pts3 = Replace[pts2, {x_, y_} :> {x, y, 0}, {2}];
ptlen = pts3 // Length;
Table[arr[i] = AppendTo[pts3[[i]], pts3[[i, 1]]], {i, 1, ptlen, 1}];
Table[len[i] = Length[arr[i]], {i, 1, ptlen, 1}];
Table[rotpt[i] = 
   Table[RotationTransform[j*2 Pi/(len[i] - 1), 
      vt1 - vt2, (vt1 + vt2)/2]@arr[i][[j]], {j, 1, len[i] - 1, 
     1}], {i, 1, ptlen, 1}];
rg = 10;
Manipulate[
 Show[Graphics3D[{Thickness[.01/2], Red, 
    Table[Line@Take[arr[i], Floor[len[i] - (n*len[i]/100) + 1]], {i, 
      1, ptlen, 1}], Darker@Green, 
    Table[Line[
      RotationTransform[Ceiling[(n*len[i]/100 - 1)]/len[i]*2 Pi, 
        vt1 - vt2, (vt1 + vt2)/2]@rotpt[i]], {i, 1, ptlen, 1}]}, 
   Axes -> False, PlotRange -> rg, ViewAngle -> 0.174502, 
   ViewPoint -> {6.20078, 3.50102, 4.15851}, 
   ViewVertical -> {0.636422, 0.631119, 0.443459}, Boxed -> False, 
   Background -> Black, Lighting -> {{"Ambient", White}}], 
  ContourPlot3D[z == 0, {x, -rg, rg}, {y, -rg, rg}, {z, -rg, rg}, 
   Mesh -> None, ContourStyle -> Opacity[0.8]]], {{n, 1, "n"}, 100, 
  1, -1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, SaveDefinitions -> True, 
 ControlPlacement -> Top]



Thank you for answer. I test the code, if the letter with a "hole", result is not good.

@babyK You're right, writing highly generalized code can be very challenging. I haven't come up with a method that works for all letters yet.

@babyK Updated.

It works well, and I'm try to understand the logic of your code.

Here is an example of an implementation. First, we get the discretized boundary of the letter (thanks to @cvgmt). Then we calculate the natural parametrization of the boundary curve and construct the corresponding 3D curve.
letter = "π";
(* Shift from the rotation axis *)
shift = {3, 0};
(* Drawing canvas size *)
cs = 10;

(* Discretize boundary *)
reg = BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics[
   ImportString[ExportString[Text[Style[letter, FontFamily -> "Cambria"]], 
      "PDF"], {"PDF", "PageGraphics"}, "TextOutlines" -> True][[1, 1, 2]], 
    MaxCellMeasure -> .01];

(* Obtain boundary points *)
pts = Normal@GraphicsComplex[MeshCoordinates[reg], MeshCells[reg, 1]] /. 
   Line[{p1_, _}] :> p1 + shift;

(* Calculate natural parameter *)
phi = Accumulate[EuclideanDistance @@ # & /@ Partition[pts, 2, 1, {1, 1}]]/Perimeter[reg];

(* Merge points with the parameter *)
pts2D = Transpose[Transpose[pts]~Join~{phi}];

(* Construct 3D curve *)
pts3D[δ_] = RotationTransform[2 π #[[3]] + δ, {0, 0, 1}][{#[[1]], 0, #[[2]]}] & /@ pts2D;

(* Construct 2D interpolated curve *)
curve2D = Interpolation[{#[[3]], {#[[1]], 0, #[[2]]}} & /@ (pts2D /. δ -> 0)];

Animate[With[{δ = δ}, 
  Quiet@Show[
    Graphics3D[{Thick, Darker@Green, Line@pts3D[-2  π   δ],
       PointSize[Large], Red, Ball[curve2D[δ], .25], 
      Opacity[.75], White, 
      Polygon[{{0, 0, 0}, {cs, 0, 0}, {cs, 0, cs}, {0, 0, cs}}]}, 
     Background -> Black, Boxed -> False, BoxRatios -> {2, 2, 1}, 
     Lighting -> {{"Ambient", White}}, Axes -> True, 
     AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, Ticks -> None, 
     PlotRange -> {{-cs, cs}, {-cs, cs}, {0, cs}}, 
     ViewMatrix -> {{{0.046, 0.019, 0., 0.002}, {-0.004, 0.01, 
         0.049, -0.244}, {-0.018, 0.045, -0.011, 3.439}, {0., 0., 0., 
         1.}}, {{3.558, 0., 0.5, 0.}, {0., 3.558, 0.5, 0.}, {0., 0., 
         2.954, -7.96}, {0., 0., 1., 0.}}}], 
    ParametricPlot3D[curve2D[t], {t, 0, δ + $MachineEpsilon}, 
     PlotStyle -> {Red, Thick}], ImageSize -> {400, 300}]], {δ,0, 1}]



MMA version 12.2 provides an incorrect reg value.

@miss, hmm, I only have 12.3, in which it works fine. You may try replacing that line with something like reg = BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics[Text[Style[letter, FontFamily -> "Cambria"]], _Text, MaxCellMeasure -> {"Length" -> 0.1}]

Thanks lot. Ask for more, can i use the 3d curve as password or say to get the rotate axis, ha,ha,ha.

@babyK, uhmm, what? I don't understand what you mean :)

Sorry for not responding promptly.

@babyK. I mean put information into a curve ,eg,I sent you a curve and you guess what I say
